# ¿Cómo puedo generar 8 números aleatorios y guardarlos en una variable?

Tags: python

Quiero generar unos números aleatorios, pero que tengan una logitud de 8 caracteres, ¿cómo puedo hacer esto?

Este código me genera un número solamente, pero cómo puedo hacer que me genere 8 y los guarde en una variable:

```
from random import randint

print(randint(1, 50)) //Donde 1 y 50 son los rangos.
```

Comment: ocho numeros ejemplo "26852147"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no entiendo mal quieres generar un número de 8 cifras las cuales todas ellas son aleatorias.

**Mi propuesta**

```
from random import randint
lista = []
for x in range(8):
    a = randint(0,9)
    lista.append(str(a)) #Estas 2 líneas se pueden juntar en: lista.append(str(randint(0,9)))

valor = ''
for x in range(8):
    valor = valor + lista[x]

print (valor)
```

Se trata primero de generar esos 8 números (primer for) y luego juntarlos creando así tu número de 8 cifras (segundo for).

Cómo habrá que ir juntándolo y lo haremos con una lista lo pasamos a string para que al juntar por ejemplo 3 y 5, no nos ponga un 8, si no un 35.

Finalmente he imprimido el valor para verlo, pero si tu quisieras emplearlo a modo de entero deberías convertirlo de nuevo.

```
valor_int = int(valor)
```

Comment: para juntar varios caracteres que tienes en una lista y formar con ellos una cadena, la forma eficiente es `"".join(lista)` en lugar de `valor=valor+lista[x]`, pues esta segunda forma en cada iteración crea una cadena nueva, igual a la anterior más una letra, y asigna a `valor`  la nueva cadena creada, descartando la anterior. Se crean al final por tanto 8 cadenas diferentes, si bien `valor` sólo se refirá a la última de ellas, y el recolector de basura de python eliminará las otras 7 por no estar referenciadas. Aunque el resultado es el mismo, es más ineficiente.

Comment: Cierto!! Ahora he visto tu respuesta abajo. Aquí tu eres el maestro y yo el alumno jaja. Mi código es más para un principiante ir a paso a paso (yo soy eso). Gracias por esta aportación y en general todas las que me has hecho.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar una lista por comprensión para generarlo:

```
>>> import random
>>> [random.randint(1, 50) for _ in range(8)]
[16, 42, 40, 31, 38, 36, 49, 39]
>>> [random.randint(1, 50) for _ in range(8)]
[32, 25, 9, 20, 30, 21, 49, 49]
>>> [random.randint(1, 50) for _ in range(8)]
[15, 26, 45, 34, 8, 48, 10, 35]
```

Como pediste que fueran 8 números estoy usando un `range(8)` para repetirlo. El uso de `_` es una notación conocida que se usa cuando en realidad no te importa o no vas a usar la variable que en este caso representa a cada número del `range` (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7). No nos interesan estos números, solo nos importa que se cree el número aleatorio 8 veces.

Si quieres usar números de 8 caracteres de largo simplemente cambia el rango del `random.randint`:

```
>>> import random
>>> [random.randint(10000000, 99999999) for _ in range(8)]
[55102014, 13265201, 45930481, 49006249, 60407443, 57269930, 34855838, 82648806]
>>> [random.randint(10000000, 99999999) for _ in range(8)]
[43296217, 64608707, 42416109, 77690672, 42138288, 10231932, 11641703, 10979664]
>>> [random.randint(10000000, 99999999) for _ in range(8)]
[94958883, 48457956, 83378068, 82432246, 84746110, 55744498, 10305207, 96587844]
>>> [random.randint(10000000, 99999999) for _ in range(8)]
[64972786, 93738977, 45605234, 13633684, 61318408, 92254367, 84691648, 15943389]
```

Si nos ponemos elegantes, lo puedes hacer también usando `map`:

```
>>> map(lambda x: random.randint(1, 50), range(8))
[20, 3, 26, 32, 45, 27, 36, 1]
>>> map(lambda x: random.randint(1, 50), range(8))
[30, 32, 20, 31, 14, 46, 10, 50]
>>> map(lambda x: random.randint(1, 50), range(8))
[1, 15, 20, 38, 35, 3, 45, 15]
>>> map(lambda x: random.randint(1, 50), range(8))
[49, 15, 41, 23, 10, 37, 5, 43]
```

Que lo que hace es "mapear" cada elemento del `range` (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7) en la función anónima `lambda`, pero esta función no hace más que retornar un entero al azaar.

Por otro lado, si lo que quieres es concatenar 8 numeros aleatorios de un único dígito entonces puedes aprovechar el `reduce` para hacerlo. Me explico:

```
>>> numeros = map(lambda x: random.randint(1, 9), range(8))
>>> numeros
[4, 8, 3, 9, 3, 1, 8, 4]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), numeros)
'48393184'
```

El reduce toma cada par de elementos y les aplica una función (en este caso los concatena), el resultado de estos dos es agregado al siguiente elemento hasta acabar con todos ellos. El resultado son todos los números concatenados.

Si lo quieres en "one-liner":

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), map(lambda x: random.randint(1, 9), range(8)))
'88193234'
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), map(lambda x: random.randint(1, 9), range(8)))
'39696282'
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), map(lambda x: random.randint(1, 9), range(8)))
'13935179'
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), map(lambda x: random.randint(1, 9), range(8)))
'68733468'
```

En una función:

```
>>> def aleatorios(largo):
...   return reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), map(lambda x: random.randint(1, 9), range(largo)))
... 
>>> aleatorios(5)
'57712'
>>> aleatorios(10)
'4196799878'
>>> aleatorios(50)
'56898298227634775671735138897661871588883782919748'
```

Answer (score 2):

Voy a intentar una solución diferente:

Creamos un generador de dígitos aleatorios:

```
from random import choice

def digits():
  while True:
      yield choice("0123456789")
```

Y lo usamos para generar número de 8 dígitos:

```
from itertools import islice

n = "".join(islice(digits(), 8))
```

Lo bueno de este método es que puede generalizar para otros "alfabetos":

```
import string

def chars(alphabet):
  while True:
      yield choice(alphabet)

domain = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
pw = "".join(islice(chars(domain), 8))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas formas posibles. Dices que quieres generar 8 numeros y guardarlos en una variable (que entiendo que habría de ser una lista), por tanto puedes hacer:

```
>>> numeros = [random.randint(1,50) for i in range(8)]
numeros
[34, 29, 8, 34, 11, 39, 34, 20]
```

Aunque también dices "numeros aleatorios, pero que tengan una longitud de 8 caracteres", lo que está menos claro. ¿Hablamos de 8 números, o de un solo número de 8 dígitos?

Si es lo segundo puedes generar 8 cifras entre 1 y 9 y convertir cada una de ellas en cadena para finalmente juntarlas todas con `join()`, así:

```
>>> resultado = "".join(str(n) for n in (random.randint(1,9) for i in range(8)))
resultado
'57818267'
```

Answer (score -1):

Puede hacerlo de la siguiente manera importando la librería `random` y haciendo un cliclo `for` como muestro continuación

```
import random
for x in range(8):
print random.randint(1,50)
```